# Why is the App Center dialog in my Android App not showing download buttons anymore?

Tags: android, visual-studio-app-center

We use Microsoft App Center to allow an in app update dialog outside of the Play Store.

With our current version the buttons in this dialog are not visible anymore.

The dialog looks like this: [image]

The Buttons are white text on white background, this makes it really hard for our users to update the app.

We are using Microsoft Appcenter version 3.2.1.

As Anastasia pointed out in a comment this happens because we are using Material Components in the App, the non Material Dialog that Appcenter uses is not able to deal with the Material Styles.

We build our own custom dialog for the update notification.
Sadly this is not the only dialog the appcenter is showing.
So after clicking the custom download button our users now get the next broken dialog:

[image]

Comment: Probably it related to the theme setting in the application. As an alternative way, you can customize the update dialog as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/distribute/android#2-customize-the-update-dialog.